# How pass parameters from url to another bean using jsf

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, parameter-passing

i will explain. How I can pass param get on click button and pass another bean and redirect to another page. Is code is:

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
   <h:dataTable ... >
      <h:column>
         <f:facet name="header">Responder</f:facet>
            <h:commandButton value="Responder e-mail" class="btn btn-info" action="#{respostaBean.responder(registro)}" />
      </h:column>
   </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

When click in commandButtton I want that show a bean:

**RespostaController.java**

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "respostaBean")
public class RespostaController implements Serializable {
  ...
   public String responder(Registro registro){
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.persist(resposta);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
        manager.close();
        return "responder?faces-redirect=true";
    }
...
```

And after click button need show this page and pass id for show in another page.

**responder.xhtml**

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="companyId" value="#{registroBean.registro.id}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{registroBean.responder}" />
</f:metadata>

Responder protocolo:
    <h:outputText value="#{registroBean.registro.protocolo}" />
```

But since I am not able to pass the parameter, the protocol is not being shown. Resuming: I just want to pass the parameter to another URL because I want to use it on another page along with another bean (respostaBean and registroBean). Because I have two bean, and a one-to-one relationship between them, so I need to pass the parameter to the responder.xhtml page. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. You pass `registro` to the action method `responder`, but you don't use it in the method. And you don't show us `registroBean`. Where should we know what your problem is? If you need help post the relevant parts of both beans.

Comment: Basically I want pass a variable with params for another view. In index.xhtml I used registroBean and set all attributes for registro (protocolo, details...), save on db and show in datatable the register. After onclick button go to responder.xhtml. This view use the bean responderBean and have a one-to-one relationship and I need pass register (id in the case) for this view because I want show a outputtext registro.procolo in the view. Basically is just this, show in another view.